react-three-fiber different textures on front and back of a planeGeometry
I'm attempting to show two different textures on the two sides of a planeGeometry component. It's possible that I'm misunderstanding how planes work and this isn't possible, but I thought with the side property I could apply one texture to the front side and one to the back side. With how I currently have it implemented it seems like only the back side texture is rendering.
Is this possible? If so, what am I missing to make this work? If not, is there a suggested work-around (i.e. having two different planeGeometry objects back to back)?
Any help is appreciated!
Here's the code for how it's implemented right now:
// using useTexture helper from @react-three/drei
const [frontTexture, backTexture] = useTexture(["<front texture URL>", "<rear texture URL>"]);

return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={meshRef}
    >
      <planeGeometry args={[ 1, 1 ]} />
      <meshBasicMaterial
        attach="material"
        map={frontTexture}
        side={FrontSide}
      />
      <meshBasicMaterial
        attach="material"
        map={backTexture}
        side={BackSide}
      />
    </mesh>
);

